# Subtracting date&time with format of yyyymmddhhmmss

Tags: shell-script, date, variable, arithmetic

I have two date/time values in `yyyymmddhhmmss` format in shell variables.
I want to subtract one from the other and get the result in seconds like below:

```
a=20170804020000
b=20170804015959
c=a-b
```

The result I want is `c=1` (because `02:00:00` is one second later than `01:59:59`), but I got `c=4041`.

How can I subtract date/time values to have result in seconds?

Comment: @JeffSchaller i didnt get you well

Comment: @JeffSchaller mi is minute and i want the diff to be in second not as a decimal number

Comment: Please demonstrate how you are currently subtracting and how you want it to be different.

Comment: @JeffSchaller i want to change the type to date then diff do you have any idea how to do that

Comment: @JeffSchaller no not just second also minute

Comment: Convert time to unix time before substraction? Result gives you the difference in seconds (which can be converted to desired units). This would be simpler with different programming environment to shell imo.

Comment: @sebasth is there a way to convert to date type in unix

Answer (score 4, accepted):

First you need to convert the dates to unix time_t format (i.e. seconds since the "epoch", 1970-01-01 00:00:00).  Then you can calculate the difference with a simple subtraction.

The dates you have are not understood by the `date` program in their current format.  It expects something that looks more like a date with dashes and colons separating the fields than a number.

Here's an example that uses `sed` in a function to "fix" the dates - i.e. convert them to a format understood by `date`, then uses `date` to convert to time_t seconds, then do the subtraction:

```
#!/bin/bash

a=20170804020000
b=20170804015959

function fixdate() {
  printf "$1" | sed -E -e 's/(....)(..)(..)(..)(..)(..)/\1-\2-\3 \4:\5:\6/'
}

a_seconds="$(date -d "$(fixdate "$a")" '+%s')"
b_seconds="$(date -d "$(fixdate "$b")" '+%s')"
seconds=$((a_seconds - b_seconds))

echo "$seconds"
```

Comment: btw, the `fixdate` function definition isn't necessary.  I wrote it this way because: 1. "DRY" or "Don't Repeat Yourself" - if you find yourself doing the same thing repeatedly, turn it into a function or subroutine.  2. it's a lot more readable this way. 3. i hate horizontal scroll bars, especially when reading code.

Comment: I think he downvoted it because he doesn't understand it.

Comment: Oh btw you missed the bang in your #!

Comment: actually i am new to unix and i didn't know how to build a function thanks m8 you helped a lot :)

Answer (score 1):

It's not pretty but this worked for me in centos:

```
a=20170804020000

b=20170804015959

ayear=${a:0:4}
amonth=${a:4:2}
aday=${a:6:2}
ahour=${a:8:2}
amin=${a:10:2}
asec=${a:12:2}

byear=${b:0:4}
bmonth=${b:4:2}
bday=${b:6:2}
bhour=${b:8:2}
bmin=${b:10:2}
bsec=${b:12:2}

adate=$(date -d "$amonth/$aday/$ayear $ahour:$amin:$asec" +"%s")
bdate=$(date -d "$bmonth/$bday/$byear $bhour:$bmin:$bsec" +"%s")
datediff=$((adate-bdate))
```

Comment: this could be a lot shorter using sed to transform the dates to a format understood by the `date` program, e.g. `adate="$(date -d "$(printf "$a" | sed -E -e 's/(....)(..)(..)(..)(..)(..)/\1-\2-\3 \4:\5:\6/')" '+%s')"`

Answer (score 0):

You can do math operations with dates by converting them in Unix format. But for do that, first you'll need to give those values (yyyymmddhhmmss) some proper format (yyyy-mm-dd hh:mm:ss).

Then you could do something like:

```
$ a=$(date -d '2017-08-04 02:00:00' '+%s')
$ b=$(date -d '2017-08-04 01:59:59' '+%s')
$ c=$((a-b))
$ echo $a
1501830000
$ echo $b
1501829999
$ echo $c
1
```

Comment: This is just my answer without actually being an answer at all.