# Fixing problem with %(%H)T giving 12 hour

Tags: bash, time

I am passing a time interval (in seconds) in `ts`.

```
ts=13
printf -v hours '%(%H)T' "$ts"
printf '%s\n' "ts: $ts ; hours: $hours"
```

This is the incorrect result.

ts: 13 ; hours: 12

As one can see, I am getting `12` rather than `00` for 13 seconds.

Comment: Also note that the Unix timestamp `13` corresponds to `Thu Jan  1 01:00:13 CET 1970` (or `Thu Jan  1 00:00:13 UTC 1970`).

Comment: @Kusalananda, it does set `hours` to `12`, if you have `TZ=NZ` or such. Or if you have `TZ=Europe/Helsinki`, it sets it to `02`. And to `00` if `TZ=UTC`. Anyway, the timezone affects that, so it might well be the problem.

Comment: @ilkkachu Thanks, I was searching for what timezone they might be using.  New Zealand may well be it.

Comment: Why should tho timezone affect such conversion? Kamchatka (Russian Far East) timezone actually.

Comment: @Alta As I wrote in my previous comment, the timestamp `13` corresponds to some time in January 1970 (UTC).  Depending on what your timezone is, asking for the hour component of that timestamp will differ (since the hour differs for any specific time depending on timezone).

Comment: @Alta, the arg to `%(...)T` is seconds since the epoch, i.e. since Jan 1 1970 00:00:00 UTC. That is, it's a point in time, not a time _interval_.

Comment: @ilkkachu Their questions (elsewhere) is currently all about measuring time using `$EPOCHREALTIME`, and their `$ts` is likely a time difference, and they probably think that the code converts a set of seconds to hours, minutes and seconds.

Comment: It is then evident that it is inappropriate to use `printf -v hours '%(%H)T' "$ts"` for computing time interval conversion to days, hours, minutes, and seconds.

Comment: I think it should work with `TZ=UTC` and `%j %H %M %S`. you'll get the days, hours etc. with no timezone offset, but will need to subtract one from the days since it starts counting at 1. E.g. `eval "$(TZ=UTC printf "%(daysplus1=%j hours=%H mins=%M secs=%S)T" "$((3*86400 + 7*3600))" )"` would set `daysplus1` to **4**, `hours` to 7 and `mins`=`secs`=0

Comment: @ilkkachu Feel free to summarize in an answer. It's been reopened.

Comment: @Kusalananda, thank you.

Comment: Are you trying to calculate a time interval? If so, [this answer](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/387012/100397) may well help

Answer (score 0):

As discussed in comments, I think your problem is the timezone. `%(...)T` prints the time in local time, so e.g. I get

```
$ printf "%(%F %T %z)T\n" "$(date +%s)"
2021-08-21 19:58:45 +0300
```

But you should be able to set the `TZ` variable to change the timezone:

```
$ TZ=UTC printf "%(%F %T %z)T\n" "$(date +%s)"
2021-08-21 16:59:45 +0000
```

In particular, the argument there is the seconds after the epoch, so after Jan 1 1970 00:00:00 UTC. It's a point in time, not a time interval. But we can treat it as an interval length for small enough values if we squint a bit, make sure to use UTC (so the time zone doesn't matter), and ignore the years.

The `strftime()` specifier `%j` would give the day of the year between 001 and 366, so using that along with `%H %M %S`, we can get days, hours, minutes and seconds, up to a years worth. Just note that there's the offset of one in the days:

```
$ TZ=UTC printf "%(%j %H %M %S)T\n" "$(( 123*86400 + 7*3600 + 6*60 + 5))"
124 07 06 05
```

Or, with some eval trickery, this would assign the values to variables:

```
$ eval "$(TZ=UTC printf "%(daysplus1=%j hours=%H mins=%M secs=%S)T" \
                        "$(( 123*86400 + 7*3600 + 6*60 + 5))" )"
$ days=$((daysplus1 - 1))
$ echo $days $hours $mins $secs
123 07 06 05
```

Of course you could just use `days=$((ts / 86400))` to get the days, and you wouldn't be limited by one year's worth.

Or just calculate them all manually:

```
secs=$(( ts % 60)); 
mins=$(( ts / 60 % 60 )); 
hours=$(( ts / 3600 % 24));
days=$(( ts / 86400 ));
```

<sub>(That `eval` trick was picked up from some of [Stéphane](https://unix.stackexchange.com/users/22565/st%c3%a9phane-chazelas)'s answers, but I can't remember which one.)</sub>

Comment: I will go through the manual route.  Many thanks.

Comment: Is this valid in bash ? `(( days = ts / (60*60*24) ))`

Comment: @Alta looks valid to me. that `((...))` isn't standard but works in Bash/ksh/zsh

Comment: The "eval trick" was already used in this 2004 post [eval `date "+day=%d; month=%m; year=%Y`](http://www.linuxmisc.com/12-unix-shell/55d991c54b9ed0fc.htm). I am sure that the origin is even older.